# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener

Tags: struts2, classnotfoundexception, tiles

```java
15:06:38,636 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myapp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011093: Could not load component class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener from [Module "deployment.myapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
    ... 7 more

15:06:39,542 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 92339ms - Started 144 of 219 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 71 services are passive or on-demand)
15:06:39,543 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "myapp.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myapp.war\""}}
15:06:40,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myapp.war in 853ms
15:06:40,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myapp.war"

15:06:40,399 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myapp.war\""}}}}
```

Comment: At least put some effort in rather than just posting an exception, what are you trying to do, at what point does it appear etc.

Comment: Add missing jar file struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.8.jar

Comment: Try deploying on glassfish/tomcat because they are quite popular and someone here might understand their logs better... and more explanation would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had added more dependencies than those that were needed.
The only dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.12</version>
</dependency>
```